# How to filter workfront issue by parameterValues

Tags: workfront-api

Is it possible to filter by parameterValues using the workfront API? Something like this?

```
/attask/api/v10.0/issue/search?apiKey=YOURAPIKEY&$$LIMIT=10&parameterValues>DE:CUSTOMNUMBER=12345&fields=*,parameterValues
```

I cannot find any documentation on filtering by parameterValues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a friend who gave me a hint.  Here is how you filter by a parameter Value:

```
/attask/api/v10.0/issue/search?apiKey=YOURAPIKEY&$$LIMIT=10&DE:CUSTOMNUMBER=12345&fields=*,parameterValues
```